# Dynamic input to sql query Using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dynamic-data

I have a hyperlink which should print information from sql database.But I'm not able to know how to give that hyperlink value to sql query.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=ILLUMINATI;" + "Database=DB;Integrated Security= true");
        SqlDataAdapter ADP = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from News where Headlines= au_id", conn);
```

I want to get value au_id dynamically can anybody help me with this after clicking on the hyperlink.

Its like when i click on the headlines i should get the corresponding news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use a `LinkButton` instead of a `Hyperlink` control as hyperlink redirects the page to a specified URL. But the LinkButton has a Click Event handler. On that click you can get the ID.

Your query will be look like...

```
SqlDataAdapter ADP = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from News where Headlines = " + au_id, conn);
```

But It would be better if you use a `Parameterized query to save yourself from a SQL Injection Attack`.

```
SqlDataAdapter ADP = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from News where Headlines = @au_id", conn);
ADP.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@au_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, "au_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you exactly want, but here is simple example :

```
using ( command = new SqlCommand( ("select * from News where Headlines=" + au_id ), conn) //send au_id as string variable
{
    DataTable outDT = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(outDT); 
        return outDT; // Your DataTable
}
```